# Difference between Debug and Release folders

Tags: vb.net

Could you advise me what is the difference between Debug and Release folders?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear, the name of the folders in your question are virtually unlimited (not simply limited to debug and release). Right click on your solution and select Configuration Manager and you can add as many configurations as you would like. The name of the configuration is the name of the folder.

As Joshua wrote, usually, people use their debug config to include things like the .pdb file (which includes debugging symbols needed to get line numbers from errors, etc.). Release is normally cleaner. However, you can easily setup folders for x86 vs. x64 vs. any cpu.

If you have a solution with 10 different projects (not uncommon if you work on something of decent size) you might want to build certain projects together and others together. In this case, you should create additional configurations to support this so you can build a group simply by changing your active configuration.

In the end, the folders you mentioned contain whatever you specify in the configuration manager that they should contain.

Answer (score 5):

The debug folder usually contains your program compiled for debugging, that is there is additional information included, such as variable names, that help you find errors in the program.

The release folder contains your program without any of that. Just what is necessary for the program to run.